# Make the edit link for question be more noticeable

Tags: feature-request

Instead of editing questions folks write lots of comments.

I usually type "please use the [edit] link to add more information on your original question", and the usual response is one or more comments with the requested information.

[image]

After endless times experiencing this, it is clear to me that the [**edit**] link is not so clear to others.

Is there a way to make it stand out more as a clickable link? Should it have a box around it or some other design element?

[image]

Comment: While I agree with your reasoning, this would just clutter the screen for me, since I already know where the Edit button is. This would probably work better as a feature that disappears after the user has 20 rep or similar.

Comment: Most users do not see the edit option... Sometimes I even write "use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (between share and close)" but even then most folks just write more comments...

Comment: or tell everybody to turn on [keyboard navigation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/curent) and just press `E` on any question page.

Comment: @David thanks! Where would I find such shortcuts?

Comment: To me making it more visible isn't really going to work; there's a [popup asking if user is sure they'd like to answer their question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxOwP.jpg) anyway. If they don't see that then chances are they won't see any buttons below the question as well. Probably some more visual information on that popup could work while I'm not sure

Comment: Ok... so from now on, I will keep it very simple: "Please press **E** to [edit] the question (or try the link at the bottom of the post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) ... or leave a comment if that is too complicated..."

Comment: @cegaton no, no. keyboard navigation is **not** on by default, you can't tell users to simply press **E**.

Comment: @David bummer...